# How to load a dynamic webpage content in a new tab

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on a Backbone JS application in which I've got to load some dynamic data in a new tab, which is currently loading in the same page.
The existing thing with backbone is to use **app.navigate()** method #same page.

I tried using window.open(), and wrote a method onload() of it like this.

```
var newWindow = window.open(openUrl+"#catalog2/"+genTimestamp(), '_blank');

newWindow.onload = function() {
app.navigate("/catalog2/"+genTimestamp(), false); 
};
```

But the script is loading / applying on the parent window, instead of the newly opened window, as a result of which, the new page is not loading properly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `app` references the app object of the **parent** window, that's why your parent window is being loaded/applied.

Comment: @Ignaus Makes sense. But I don't have any alternative to route to that page, except using the navigate(). Do you have any other info that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone works very well for single page application.

Once you open a new window it's, by definition, no longer a single page application, and your routes or history object will not be applicable to the other window, since each window has its own history.

instead you could use good old [`newWindow.location.assign(url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)